# How can I install TeXMaker 3?

Tags: 11.04, installation, latex

When trying to install TeXMaker 3 in Ubuntu 11.04 with the package available with the 32bit package at http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html I get the following error:

```
Preparing to replace texmaker 2.2.1-1ubuntu1 (using .../texmaker_ubuntu_11.04_3.0.1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement texmaker ...
dpkg: error processing /home/ingo/Downloads/texmaker_ubuntu_11.04_3.0.1_i386.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texmaker/doc12.png', which is also in package texmaker-data 2.2.1-1ubuntu1
dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal gzip write error: Broken pipe
dpkg-deb (subprocess): failed in write on buffer copy for failed to write to pipe in copy: Broken pipe
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for python-gmenu ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/desktop.en_US.UTF8.cache...
Processing triggers for python-support ...
```

I tried to use `sudo gdebi ...` as a workaround, but that did not work. How can I install TeXMaker otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That website says:

> Uninstall first all previous version.